# Store and Query Time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am designing a database for userEvent data. I will be storing their running event and time. So for example 1500 meters in 5:00 or 10,000 meters in 30:20.

The database will be recieving the user data via the UI with 4 select dropdowns for `hours` `minutes` `seconds` and `milliseconds`.

One of the queries I will need to perform on this database is to find all of the users who run a specific event faster then a specific time. So for example All 1500 meter runners under 4:30.

I am new to SQL and this query is not really coming to me. Because a 5:00 minute 1500 meter time will be stored in the db as `0 | 5 | 0 | 0` for hours minutes seconds and milliseconds but I will need to find all those faster then `0 | 4 | 30 | 0`.

What is the best way to store and query this userEvent data? Thanks!

Comment: Don't store these values in separate columns

Comment: So how should they be stored? 0:5:0:0 ?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have your data split in different columns, you could do like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE
event = 'event1'
AND hours*3600+minutes*60+seconds+milliseconds/1000 <
0*3600+4*60+30+0/1000 ;
```

[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26bb0/1)

But maybe it would be better to store a single field containing, for example, the amount of milliseconds.

Comment: Ahhhh so store it as milliseconds and then query that for lower or higher. That makes sense thank you. Could I get into issues for say a 5 hour marathoner? That'd be a lot of milliseconds is there a limit on how many integers I can have in an INT?

Comment: 5 hour in ms is 18,000,000 ms  (https://www.google.no/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=5+hour+in+milliseconds&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ahndU-jKDYSA8Qfwv4DoBw) and an INT in mySql is able to store a value up to 2,147,483,647 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is use to convert to the lowest precision.

Example store everything in millisecons.

1 min = 60000.

so if someone asks <2 mins just query for time<120000;

If you have existing data just convert the data using a Stored Procedure or ant language to milliseconds.

Hope it works.